# Retrieving Attributes from Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

Probably a very simple answer that I am just not finding. I have created a database of movies, I am able to find all movies simply enough with

```
    Movie.findAll().then(function(movies){

    movies.forEach(console.log);  
    });
```

What I want to do is be able to target the specific attributes of the movies as illustrated below, but I have no idea what to reference.

```
    Movie.findAll().then(function(movies){

    movies.forEach(console.log(THIS MOVIE TITLE));  
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply find the title of each movie inside the movies array.

Might be like this:

```
   Movie.findAll().then(function(movies){

   movies.forEach(movie => console.log(movie.title));  
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a another way to get movie names.

You can specify the attribute names so you will get only those columns.

```
Movie.findAll({
  attributes: ['title']
}).then((movies) => {
});
```

By this, you get the array of an object which contains movie titles.